# change of default search-engine on Safari

Tags: mac, safari, search-engines

So I got this problem - I installed Internet Explorer on my Mac and an add-on program came with it (XQuarz). And after this all the default search engine in Safari is got changed to ChatZilla (wtf?!) and even when I set from the options back to Google - it is still with ChatZilla. 
Perhaps I must remove the XQartz thingy but it doesn't show up in the program so I can't find where to remove it from... suggestions on all of these things ?